How to set correct type declare in webwiew app?
I'am building my webview app (using vue3 + typescript) for my vscode extension.
When I try to use vscode api in this webview app, like window.vscode.postMessage(data), ts-plugin will throw an error that Property vscode does not exist on type Window & typeof globalThis.
Now I can declare the type by this
declare global {
  interface Window {
    vscode?: any;
  }
}

How can I correctly declare type of vscode(rather than any)? I can't find relevant information on the vscode official website

It doesn't work because it's actually the other way around. The type "window" is defined on type "vscode". You just need to do a normal import in your webview:
import { TextEditor, Uri, Webview, window, workspace } from "vscode";

and then you can use those types, for example:
void window.showErrorMessage("I've got an error");

Don't forget to install @types/vscode as dev dependency.

My goal is to use window.vscode.xxx in my frontend(webview). It should be noted that window.vscode.xxx can work normally, but there is a type error. However, after import { window } from 'vscode', these type errors still exist.

Not sure why you want to go that route. I showed you how it works perfectly, why trying to make something else work, that's obviously not doing what you want?
